# Java Actor in sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have written one sbt project. With spray for APIs and using Akka for actors in scala language.

I'm following a simple pattern of writing actor

```
def receive = {
  case message: DataActorMessage => message match {
     case m: GetMessage => {
      ...
     }
}
package message {
   sealed trait DataActorMessage
   case class GetMessage() extends DataActorMessage
   .
   .
   .
}
```

so actors are written in scala. So with existing actors written in scala Can we have a new actor written as separate Java Class?

Comment: Akka also has a Java api. So, you can also write actors in Java. And why are you using Spray in a new project ? Spray development stopped around 5 years back. It is replaced by akka-http.

Comment: Scala runs on top of the JVM, you can natively use Java code with Scala code. Java cannot natively interact with Scala code (though you can use scalac [the scala compiler] to compile your Scala code into Java code, at which point you could use Java to interact with that code).

Comment: Totally agreed on spray and use akka-http. And I have started doing migration just that currently it is a spray that's why I mentioned spray in here